# problem with installing softwares on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, 16.04

I've recently installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my PC and have several problems with installing softwares.

first of all, it seems that I don't have software center at all.
I only have ubuntu software and app grid and even they don't properly work.I cannot download and install any software with them.

I Also have a problem with terminal.I don't know how to install packages with terminal.
I use this code:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package name>.deb
```

I've tried to install VLC player and Chrome with this code, but I face an error:

[image: Installing VLC] and
[image: Installing Chrome]

Comment: Why not install VLC by `sudo apt install vlc`? You do not need to download it. And it looks like you downloaded a wrong `i386` package. Ubuntu Software replaced Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Put the errors in text format, not in screenshot. That makes the post easier to see

Comment: I agree with Pilot6 - don't overcomplicate installing software, at least as long as it is available via `apt`.  Your `dpkg` usage looks fine so far, but was most likely using wrong local packages (32 vs 64bit). The one thing you should check out is why Ubuntu Software is not working for you. Any error  messages you get?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the old "Software Center" has been removed, and replaced by "Ubuntu Software", which is actually just "Gnome Software" rebranded.

Comment: @dufte , That command does not work for me. honestly, I don't know how to exactly use that.  how I can install a software by that command without downloading anything?

Comment: Also, my problem with Ubuntu Software is that I can't find any software at all! I don't get any error messages. I search for a software but I get the message "No Application Found".

Comment: @pooya Ubuntu is not like Windows. `apt` finds the software in a repository, downloads it, and installs it. It's called a [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager).

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to execute one more command, as follows:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: I use that second command to remove a software that has not been properly installed.  would you please explain more how to use that second command?

Answer (score 0):

I found why Ubuntu Software and `apt` code were not working. By mistake I had unchecked some essential option boxes in Software & Updates.I can now install softwares.

Thank you all!

Comment: For the sake of people who may have this issue in the future, please explain which exact settings caused the problem.